# How Can I optimize indexing column in table?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I am trying to add an index to my MySQL DB because the query speed is too slow in the statistics database used by the system.

It takes about 30 min to get 1 min statistics out over 50,000 tuple

At first, I tried to add an index per columns but it results DB performance degradation. Because the query uses multiple columns, I should use the indexes that are actually used.

The actual query that I use is below in simple version.
the condition can change,

```
SELECT TIME,A,B,C,D,E,F,G FROM STAT_TBL1 WHERE TIME >='2019-07-04 16:00:00' AND TIME <='2019-07-04 16:59:59' AND H IN ('blah1') AND I IN ('blah2') ORDER BY TIME
SELECT TIME,A,B,C,D,E,F,G FROM STAT_TBL2 WHERE TIME >='2019-07-04 16:00:00' AND TIME <='2019-07-04 16:59:59' AND J IN ('blah3') AND K IN ('blah4') ORDER BY TIME
SELECT TIME,A,B,C,D,E,F,G FROM STAT_TBL3 WHERE TIME >='2019-07-04 16:00:00' AND TIME <='2019-07-04 16:59:59' AND H IN ('blah1') AND I IN ('blah2') AND J IN ('blah3') AND K IN ('blah4') ORDER BY TIME
```

I've tried to create the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_LIST1_01 ON STAT_TBL1 (TIME)
CREATE INDEX IDX_LIST1_02 ON STAT_TBL1 (H)
CREATE INDEX IDX_LIST1_03 ON STAT_TBL1 (I)

CREATE INDEX IDX_LIST2_01 ON STAT_TBL3 (TIME)
CREATE INDEX IDX_LIST2_02 ON STAT_TBL3 (J)
CREATE INDEX IDX_LIST2_03 ON STAT_TBL3 (K)

CREATE INDEX IDX_LIST3_01 ON STAT_TBL3 (TIME)
CREATE INDEX IDX_LIST3_02 ON STAT_TBL3 (H)
CREATE INDEX IDX_LIST3_03 ON STAT_TBL3 (I)
```

Which is better; to add an index per column or an index with multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

An index with multiple columns will be usually faster. Use date for the multiple-column index(es) and one or two other columns that you usually use to filter your data. If you filter your data with a lot of different columns that differ from query to query, you will have to create that many indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  TIME,A,B,C,D,E,F,G
    FROM  STAT_TBL1
    WHERE  TIME >='2019-07-04 16:00:00'
      AND  TIME <='2019-07-04 16:59:59'
      AND  H IN ('blah1')
      AND  I IN ('blah2')
    ORDER BY  TIME
```

is best indexed thus:

```
INDEX(H, I, TIME)  -- H and I in either order, then TIME
```

Also, I suggest this for the time comparison:

```
    WHERE  TIME >= '2019-07-04 16:00:00'
      AND  TIME  < '2019-07-04 16:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Might you have more than one value in `IN()`?  If not, simply say

```
      AND  H = 'blah1'
      AND  I = 'blah2'
```

For tbl2:

```
INDEX(J, K,  -- in either order
      TIME)  -- last
```

For tbl3:

```
INDEX(H, I, J, K,  -- in any order
      TIME)        -- last
```

If there is only one element in each `IN()`, then the `ORDER BY TIME` can be acted upon by the `INDEXes` I gave you, thereby making it even faster by not having to sort.

When there are more elements in `IN()`, the index will still be useful, but not for avoiding the sort.

More on index creation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: you mean that if I put the Time column in index, Dont I have to use ORDER BY TIME?

Comment: @반애솔 - No, keep the `ORDER BY`.  What I mean is that the Optimizer won't have to do any extra effort to deliver the results in `TIME` order.